# modelsummary unexpected latex output

Tags: latex, regression, modelsummary

With the following code I produce the laTex table in the image below. As you might notice there are a few things wrong with the output.

1. The title is missing
2. P-values in the wrong place
3. The footnote is misaligned

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
library(tidyverse)
library(modelsummary)
library(gt)


data <- as.data.frame(ChickWeight)
mod_control <- lm(weight ~ Time , data = data)
mod_treat <- lm(weight ~ Time + Diet, data = data)


mod_one_list <- list(mod_control, mod_treat)

# coefmap
cm <- c("(Intercept)"="Konstant",
        "Time" = "Tid",
        "Num.Obs." = "n")

# gof_map 
gm <- list(list(raw = "nobs", clean = "N", fmt = 0))

# title
tit <- "En beskrivning här"


# produce table


modelsummary(mod_one_list, 
                          output = "gt",
                          stars = T,
                          title = tit,
                          coef_map = cm,
                          gof_map = gm,
                          vcov = "HC1") %>%  
  tab_spanner(label = '(1)', columns = 2) %>%
  tab_spanner(label = "(2)", columns = 3) %>% 
  tab_footnote("För standardfel använder vi HC1",
               locations = cells_body(rows = 1, columns = 2)) %>%
  as_latex() %>%
  cat()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue with the `gt` package. When adding both footnotes and
source notes (which is what `modelsummary` uses to report significance
stars), `gt` puts both types of notes in different mini-pages. This
breaks alignment in LaTeX.

You can see this by inspecting the code of this minimal example:

```r
library(gt)

dat <- mtcars[1:4, 1:4]

gt(dat) |> 
  tab_source_note(source_note = "source note") |> 
  tab_footnote("footnote", locations = cells_body(rows = 1, columns = 2)) |> 
  as_latex() |> 
  cat()
```

```
## \captionsetup[table]{labelformat=empty,skip=1pt}
## \begin{longtable}{rrrr}
## \toprule
## mpg & cyl & disp & hp \\ 
## \midrule
## 21.0 & 6\textsuperscript{1} & 160 & 110 \\ 
## 21.0 & 6 & 160 & 110 \\ 
## 22.8 & 4 & 108 & 93 \\ 
## 21.4 & 6 & 258 & 110 \\ 
##  \bottomrule
## \end{longtable}
## \vspace{-5mm}
## \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
## \textsuperscript{1}footnote \\ 
## \end{minipage}
## \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
## source note\\ 
## \end{minipage}
```

I am not sure if the `gt` maintainers would consider this a “bug”, but
it might be worth it to report it on their repository anyway:
https://github.com/rstudio/gt/issues

For what it’s worth, I think that the default LaTeX output with
`modelsummary(model, output="latex")` generally works better, because it
uses `kableExtra`, which seems to prioritize LaTeX a bit more.